# finding documents in array i mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of albums, example of album:

```
var album = {
    name: 'album1',
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
                {name: 'someTask', started: '12/12/12' },
                {name: 'someTask', started: '12/10/12' },
                {name: 'anotherTask', started: '12/12/10', finished: '12/12/10' }
            ]
        }


    },{
        title: 'track1',
        language: 'en',
    },{
        title: 'track2',
        language: 'es',
    }]
}
```

How can I achieve the following 1) for particular album and track I need to select tasks by name, for example (all 'someTask' for Album1 and track0)

2) The second problem is to select last task in tasks that is not finished.

So, for the first query as a result I need to get:

```
{
    name: 'album1'
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
               {name: 'someTask', started: '12/12/12' },
               {name: 'someTask', started: '12/10/12' },
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

For the second query as a result I need to get:

```
{
    tracks: [{
        title: 'track0',
        language: 'en',
        processing: {
            tasks: [
                {name: 'someTask', started: '12/10/12' },
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

So I want to select only one tasks that satisfy the criteria. I tried different varians with $elemMath like:

```
tracks: {$elemMatch: {'processing.tasks': {$elemMatch:{name: 'someTask'}}}}
```

But in the result I get all processing.tasks not only tasks with the name 'someTask'.

I know how to get the second one using aggregate can I do it with find
The second one is more complex, I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Working with multiply nested arrays in documents is a recipe for a bad time. Have you considered making tasks into separate documents, ones that reference the parent track or album?